# pythonic way to copy all function inputs

Tags: python, func

I am looking for a more elegant way in order to avoid having the following:

```
def funct(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5):
   input1_new = copy.copy(input1)
   input2_new = copy.copy(input2)
   input3_new = copy.copy(input3)
   input4_new = copy.copy(input4)
   input5_new = copy.copy(input5)
```

As I am currently having many files, using very extensive functions I was wondering if there is no more pythonic way to copy all inputs given in the function.

I am copying because of the stack and heap problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Use for loops and `exec()`, it is pythonic

Comment: ^ use loops and `list`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `*` in your function's argument definition to receive all the inputs at once.

```py
def funct(*inputs):
    inputs_new = copy.copy(inputs)
```

This way you will receive all the inputs in the `inputs` tuple and you can access them iteratively. For example, `inputs[0]` will be your `input1` and etc.

Comment: I like this solution, however this would make my code significantly less readable

Comment: Well it's the most _pythonic_ way I can think of. Plus most python users got use to `*` and `**` (which receives the inputs as a dictionary instead of tuple). Also, you can put a few comments in your code and link to an external source (like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/)) for more explanation.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
def funct(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5):
   for i in range(1,100):
       exec(f"input{i}_new = f'Hi input{i}'")
       exec(f'print(input{i}_new)')
```

This will print 'input1' ... 'input99'. Similarly, you can use exec to increase the number